# $(...).wikiEditor is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, wikitext

I tried to customise the toolbar using a user script, following the tutorial on [MediaWiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor/Toolbar_customization); however, **sometimes** when I load it from my `common.js`, I get this error in my console:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).wikiEditor is not a function TypeError: $(...).wikiEditor is not a function
    at quickMAR_add (https://en.moegirl.org/index.php?title=User:Leranjun/quickMAR.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript:52:19)
    at https://en.moegirl.org/index.php?title=User:Leranjun/quickMAR.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript:60:12
    at mightThrow (https://en.moegirl.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=vector&version=1o54dq6:49:598)
    at process (https://en.moegirl.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=vector&version=1o54dq6:50:269) undefined
```

What's even weirder is that it sometimes works and sometimes not… And it always works if I copy/paste the code into the console and execute it manually.

The source code is [here](https://en.moegirl.org/index.php?title=User:Leranjun/quickMAR.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript), if it's necessary.

Comment: You would only get this error if your script runs before the `wikiEditor` jQuery plugin is registered. We would need to see the HTML where you include jQuery, the plugin and your script above

Comment: @Phil My apologies, but I have no idea what you mean by the HTML and the plugin. Do you mean the editing page?

Comment: @frankly.not.frank can you please add this your html page at the top `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Oopsies, forgot to mention that I'm not a sysop and can't make global changes. What's more, other jQuery functions are completely functional, so I'm pretty certain that jQuery is already included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the toolbar to be ready:

```
mw.hook( 'wikiEditor.toolbarReady' ).add( function ( $textarea ) {
    $textarea.wikiEditor(...);
} );
```

The method [described on the documentation page you linked](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor/Toolbar_customization#Basic_setup) is less elegant but would also work.

Comment: I'm not too sure where to add this snippet though… Is it before calling the add function?

Comment: You need to wrap your `$(...).wikiEditor(...)` calls like this, to ensure that `$(...).wikiEditor` is loaded by the time you call it.